# Solving this linear transformation equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a linear transformation $T$: $\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$$
  T\left(\begin{array}{r}
\mathbf{x}
\end{array}\right)
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2x_1-4x_2-x_3-3x_4+2x_5\\
-x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_5\\
x_1-2_x2-x_3-3x_4-x_5\\
-x_1+4x_2-x_3+5x_5
\end{array}\right]
\quad
\text{for}
\quad
\mathbf{x} = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{array}\right]
\in \mathbb{R}^5
$$
I am trying to implement a certain behavior a little game, but in order to do, I need to solve the following. I would like to find a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that satisfies $T(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{Ax}$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^5$.

How would you go about this? I have an idea but I do not wish to share it at this moment, tihi :) Just in case it might influence a possible answer (a kind soul might stop by) in a bad way.

Alright, I'll do it anyway:

It seems like $\mathbf{A}$ is simply the coefficient matrix - but why? I would like some justification/calculations.

Comment: This is fundamental matrix multiplication operation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\mathbf{A}$ is the coefficient matrix !

Test it: take $\mathbf{x} = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{array}\right]
\in \mathbb{R}^5$ and compute the matrix- vector - product $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$. You should get $T\left(\begin{array}{r}
\mathbf{x}
\end{array}\right).$

Comment: But shouldn't there be some calculations to get to the fact that A is the coefficient matrix then? Like if $Ax = ...$, then by dividing by $x$ (even though I do not think you can do exactly that), we have that A = ...? It seems silly to just say "oh, this seems like the coefficient matrix" without any calculations to actually solve the equation - that was what I did.

Comment: I really would like some justification which could happen by actually, mathematically, solving the equation for $A$ like by somehow isolating it.

Comment: You cannot divide by $x$, as it is not a square matrix, and hence not invertible.